# Which way better to pass object to a Dump Component in React Native?

Tags: react-native, components, parameter-passing, react-props

Consider I have a dump component, use for display user's information.
There're 2 ways to pass user information to component:

1):

```
class UserItem extends PureComponent {
    // pass user's properties
    const {
        userName, userEmail,
    } = this.props;
    // same
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{userName}</Text>
                <Text>{userEmail}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

2):

```
class UserItem extends PureComponent {
    // pass a user object
    const {
        userName, userEmail,
    } = this.props.user;
    // same
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{userName}</Text>
                <Text>{userEmail}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

So which way I should use? I will list down some pros & cons that I know in 2 ways:

1)

pros:

- the logic is very easy to understand, there're no "magic" things happen, the component display whatever you pass in.
- can use the power of PureComponent by shallow compare state & props (https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-compare.html) so that the component only get re-render whend needed

cons:

- I have to typing many parameters passing, like `<UserItem userName={user.name} userEmail={user.email}>` (unless you use spreading operator `...user`, but you will pass all the object properties)
- I cannot use object method inside the component. for example, my User model has a method `user.totalMoneys()`, because there're some lazy calculated properties in my object.

2)

pros:

- passing looks simple: `<UserItem user={user}>`
- can use object method inside UserItem

cons:

- I cannot use the benefit of PureComponent, I have to compare my own,

Answer (score 1):

I thing the best to go is the 1, i often see the spread operator used for this, btw you can do this in the parent to avoid passing useless props :

```
class UserParent extends Component {
    const { uselessProp1, uselessProp2, ...usefullProps } = this.props;
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <UserItem {...usefullProps} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dyo, it's a very smart way to remove the redundant props.

Actually, The reason I compare these 2 ways is I come from a OOP background, and it's very convenient to pass a whole User object (because in User, I also define some methods, computed properties, etc)

I just wonder is there another way to organize my User's methods, computed properties? for example I might have `fullname` method which return `lastname + firstname`

Comment: It works with object method, you can call it in your PureComponent :`<Text> {this.props.fullname()} </Text>` but you need to have access to props used in this function (you have to pass lastname and firstname props too in this case)

Comment: Yes, I think I can pass function as well. But in OOP, I usually have some lazy computed property like this: https://gist.github.com/tranquan/4d7744f2807cf6fe8457461263109b36 , so `mCreateTimeMoment` is only be created when needed. I wonder is there anything like this I can do in FP, or by passing `object props` instead of a whole `object`. Thanks Dyo

Comment: I think your func will work fine if you're importing required modules (moment.js) in the file using it.